# Is there the concept of pipe in redis cli?

Tags: redis, pipe

In redis cli, sometimes I want to get a random value, but to do this, I have to execute `randomkey`, and copy the result as the parameter of `get`, is there a pipe so I can execute `randomkey | get` in one line to save me from copying?

Answer (score 1):

The CLI itself doesn't have that, but the operating system - if it is *nix - offers `xargs` for that:

```
~$ redis-cli FLUSHALL
OK
~$ redis-cli SET foo bar
OK
~$ redis-cli SET baz qaz
OK
~$ redis-cli RANDOMKEY | xargs redis-cli GET
"qaz"
~$ redis-cli RANDOMKEY | xargs redis-cli GET
"bar"
~$ redis-cli RANDOMKEY | xargs redis-cli GET
"qaz"
```